# Justified UIWebView text Font and text alignment

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, text-align

I'm using swift3, i trying load htmlString in WebView, i want to use right to left text alignment and custom font for show html text. how can solve this problem?

i try this but but not working

```
func ShowHtmlText() {

    webView.delegate = self
    webView.loadHTMLString(infoText, baseURL: nil)

}

  func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

     infoText = "<p style=\"text-align:justify\">\(infoText)</p>"

   infoText =  infoText.replacingOccurrences(of: "</body>", with: "<style>body{background color: color !important;}</style></body>")
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontFamily =\"Custom Font = \"Wyekan\"")

  }
```

this is my html text :

```
<div>
<p>علی شریعتی مَزینانی، مشهور به دکتر علی شریعتی&nbsp;(زادهٔ ۲ آذر ۱۳۱۲ در روستای کاهک، سبزوار &ndash; درگذشتهٔ ۲۹ خرداد ۱۳۵۶ در ساوت&zwnj;همپتون، انگلیس) نویسنده، جامعه&zwnj;شناس، تاریخ&zwnj;شناس، فیلسوف&nbsp;پژوهشگر دینی اهل ایران، از مبارزان و فعالان مذهبی و سیاسی و از نظریه&zwnj;پردازان انقلاب اسلامی ایران بود،&nbsp;که در سن۴۴سالگی&nbsp;در انگلستان درگذشت، و هم&zwnj;اکنون آرامگاه وی در مکانی نزد مقبرهٔ زینب کبری در دمشق سوریه است.</p>

<p><strong>با پاسخ به سوالات این جشنواره و اخذ امتیاز، علاوه بر بهره مندی از جایزه 1.5 میلیون ریالی، به ازای هر 20 کدشاتس یک کد طلایی شرکت در قرعه کشی سه دستگاه خودروی تیبا هاچ بک&nbsp;&nbsp;به دست بیاورید.</strong></p>

<p>نت رای می کوشد تا با برگزاری این جشنواره، شما را با این شخصیت ارزنده، بیشتر آشنا کند.</p>
</div>

<p><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">نکات:</span></span></strong></p>

<p style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-size: 14px;">- &nbsp;هر پاسخ صحیح=5 امتیاز&nbsp;و &nbsp;پاسخ غلط=2 امتیاز، امتیازات بیشتری کسب کن و شانست رو بالا ببر.<br />
- &nbsp;اگه صد در صد مطمئن هستی&nbsp;که&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size: 14px;">سوالی ایراد داره فقط کافیه که&nbsp;گزارش خطا&nbsp;بدی ما بررسی میکنیم و اگه غلط بود سوال جایگزین واست میفرستیم.<br />
- .</span></p>

<p style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-size: 14px;">​- عجله نکن و برای پیدا کردن جواب</span><span style="font-size: 14px;">&nbsp;سوالاتت خوب جستجو کن</span></p>
```

Comment: First you are loading the page AFTER injecting the code on the body, You should call the javascript at - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView { so it has dom ready

Comment: To have a better effect I would inject at htmlString the css with background color or font like this: [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</body>" withString:@"<style>body{background color: color !important;}</style></body>"];

Comment: You can do same with use of local CSS file, You just need to load local css file with html string.

Comment: @teixeiras i edit my code but still not working.

Comment: @teixeiras i get html string from web service and then show in webview

Comment: <style>body{background color: color !important;}. this is not valid, you must use css valid code. like this: <style>body {font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;padding: 100px;font-size: 13px; background-color:red !important;}</style></body>

Comment: infoText =  infoText.replacingOccurrences(of: "</body>", with: "<style>body {font-family:  IRANSans(FaNum) ;padding: 100px;font-size: 13px; background-color:red !important;}</style></body>") i try this now my text does not eject the page, but still font and alignment not change.:|

Answer (score 2):

**Try this.**

```
  func ShowHtmlText(){
        self.webView.delegate = self
        self.webView.loadHTMLString(updateDataWithFont(infoText), baseURL: nil)
  }

  func updateDataWithFont(data:String)->String{
      return String(format: "<html><body><span style=\"font-family:%@;text-align:justify\">%@</span></body></html>","Wyekan",data)
  }
```

Please Remove **webViewDidFinishLoad** code

Comment: i try this but not changing any thing.